# Discord not receiving mic

Tags: sound, microphone

In a Discord call on the desktop app and my voice cannot be heard by others. When I use Discord  through browser I can be heard. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same problem.

Disabling Noise Suppression on Discord's settings seems to unmute the microphone for some reason.

Comment: This also helped men on openSUSE Leap 15. +1

Comment: worked! ubuntu 18.10

Comment: I'm assuming that a recent update to audio drivers caused this.  I was running with noise suppression enabled until today.  I updated my system last night and when I tried to use discord today discord would not pick up the mic.  To be more accurate it *would* pick it up for less than a second then lose the mic.

Comment: Worked for me on 18.04. I also worked for me a few months ago without issues.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a new bar on the top right that appeared once I started discord.

**Before starting discord:**

[image]

**After starting discord:**

[image]

For some reason, every time I restart it, the mic volume is defaulted to zero, so I just need to slide it to an appropriate level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Based on Mike's answer:*

Set Input Volume in Discord to 100%.
Then open Settings -> Sound, Select Input tab and set Input volume to normal (10% for me).

Be aware that if you'll change the Input Volume in Discord, it will reset your Settings!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered, but just in case it helps someone else my solution turned out to be a bit different. In my case VirtualBox crashed, and for some reason this had caused Discord and other apps to see my mic but not receive any sound.

My solution was to relaunch VirtualBox, start the VM and shut it down properly. I restarted my applications and sound was restored.
I hope this helps someone.