# Discord can't work with my microphone

Tags: laptop, lenovo, microphone

I'm tried to use my B51 Lenovo microphone on Manjaro (Gnome) and Ubuntu. Microphone is work fine in all other applications, but for some reason Discord can't utilize it. Other microphones, however, work fine as well. There is no drivers fro Linux from Lenovo, as far as I can see.

Is there a way to make it work? Disabling Noise Suppression as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112959/discord-not-receiving-mic) did not worked.